# How to make wx.Frame blinking

Tags: wxpython

in one of my pet project I am creating a very simple chat inside another application. The chat is in a stand-alone wx.Frame separated from the main application. When user receives a new message I would like to make the highlighted area "blinking" in order to let the user know he received a new message. Is that possible ? I would like to make the "blinking" working even if the frame is minimized. 
I am still using python 2.7 and wxPython 2.8.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After serveral googling I found the answer:

RequestUserAttention method in wx.TopLevelWindow was what I needed.

thanks